# Dart streams, equivalent of await for

Tags: dart, async-await

I like the `await for` construct in Dart.

How can I implement something similar with a regular for loop?

Something like

```
// beware! fictional code.
var element = stream.next();
for(; stream.isEndReached(); element = stream.next()) {
  // use element here
}

// or probably it will be like this, right? 
var element = await stream.next();
for(; await stream.isEndReached(); element = await stream.next()) {
  // use element here
}
```

But I can't figure out what functions to use instead of `next()` and `isEndReached()` here. If you could give me a full example that acts exactly like `async for`, that would be great.

Edit: Here is the actual reason that I asked for this: I want to do something like this:

```
if (!stream.isEndReached()) {
  var a = await stream.next();
  // use a
}

if (!stream.isEndReached()) {
  var b = await stream.next();
  // use b
}

// have an arbitrary number of these
```

I need to consume items one by one like this. This is why I'm asking what my made up `.next()` and `.isEndReached()` methods map to which actual methods in the stream class.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437673/using-loops-with-futures-in-dart

Comment: So, using a closure with .forEach is the only option then? What I said is not possible, right?

Comment: You need to chain the calls with `then()` to ensure one is executed after the other. I don't see a way to do this with a `for` loop.

Comment: Ok even so, what are those methods that we could not wait on? Instead of my next() and isEndReached()

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your last comment. You can wait for these methods. Just `for` doesn't provide a way to delay execution until a `Future` from the previous iteration has been completed. What's the point of this discussion anyway when you can just use `await for()`?

Comment: I edited the question. I tried to clarify my last comment at the end of the question.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't make it more clear to me. What do you thing does `await for` not do that you need?

Comment: I have a stream of lines. I need to read three lines that contain some special information, then I need to read 10 lines that contain something else, then I need to read five lines that have something else, etc. I could do `await for`s for each, count number of iterations with an int, and break when I hit the desired number. But it just does not look good to me, especially since I will also have a number of single special lines. Should I just do `await for (var line in stream) { use(line); break; }` for those? Or is there a better way to consume a single line?

Comment: Another option is to have a single `await for`,  count lines with an int, and have a bunch of ifs that see which line I'm at and act accordingly. But it just looks ugly...

Comment: Maybe you want something like `StreamQueue`. See http://news.dartlang.org/2016/04/unboxing-packages-async-part-3.html You might find other useful tools in the previous two articles of this series.

Comment: Oh that's great! Thank you so much. It's `.next` and `.hasNext` of `StreamQueue` that I need. I'd love to accept it if you could just write this bit as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear this solves your issue :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [async](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/async) package contains a [StreamQueue](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/async/1.11.0/async/StreamQueue-class.html) class that might do what you want.

See also this great article http://news.dartlang.org/2016/04/unboxing-packages-async-part-3.html

`StreamQueue` provides a pull-based API for streams.

A code snipped from the article mentioned above

```
void main() async {
  var queue = new StreamQueue(new Stream.fromIterable([1, 2, 3]));
  var first = queue.next;
  var second = queue.next;
  var third = queue.next;
  print(await Future.wait([first, second, third])); // => [1, 2, 3]
}
```

**update**

WebStorm (uses a feature of the dartanalyzer) doesn't provide quick fixes for imports when nothing was yet imported from that package. It doesn't read packages if they are not refered to in your source code. As mentioned in my answer `StreamQueue` is from the `async` package. `import 'package:async/async.dart';` is usually enough (it's a convention to name the main entrypoint file (`async.dart`) of a package the same as the package) and all exported identifiers become available in your library. Otherwise you can search the source of your project and WebStorm will also search dependencies and show what library contains the `StreamQueue` class. Then you can import this file.

Comment: To use StreamQueue, I had to find this code https://github.com/dart-lang/async/blob/master/test/stream_queue_test.dart and paste `import "package:async/async.dart" show StreamQueue;` from there to my imports. I'm using WebStorm and ctrl+space with StreamQueue did not automatically import StreamQueue. Was there an easier way I could start using StreamQueue?