# My async call is returning before list is populated in forEach loop

Tags: list, file, async-await, dart, flutter

I have a routine which gets a list of filenames from the device, then reads the file(s) to build a list.  However, the calling routine always returns with zero items.  I print the filenames, so I know they exist, however, it appears that the async is returning before I read the files.  I used similar code when making an HTTP call.  But, something here is causing the routine to return the list even though it hasn't completed.  Perhaps, it is possible that I am calling it at the wrong time?  I am calling retrieveItems here:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    retrieveItems();
  }
```

Eventually I will have a refresh button, but for now I'd simply like the list to populate with the data from the files...

### --------------------

Callee

```
Future<List<String>> readHeaderData() async {
  List<String> l = new List();
  List<String> files = await readHeaders(); // Gets filenames
  files.forEach((filename) async {
    final file = await File(filename);
    String contents = await file.readAsString();
    User usr = User.fromJson(json.decode(contents));
    String name = usr.NameLast + ", " + usr.NameFirst;
    print(name);
    l.add(name);
  }
  return l;
```

---

Caller

```
void retrieveItems() async {
  LocalStorage storage = new LocalStorage();
  await storage.readHeaderData().then((item) {
      try {
        if ((item != null ) &&(item.length >= 1)) {
          setState(() {
            users.clear();
            _users.addAll(item);
          });
        } else {
          setState(() {
            _users.clear();
            final snackbar = new SnackBar(
              content: new Text('No users found.'),
            );
            scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackbar);
          });
        }
      } on FileNotFoundException catch (e) {
        print(e.toString()); //For debug only
        setState(() {
          _users.clear();
        });
      });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 121, accepted):

This code

```
Future<List<String>> readHeaderData() async {
  List<String> l = new List();
  List<String> files = await readHeaders(); // Gets filenames
  files.forEach((filename) async {
    final file = await File(filename);
    String contents = await file.readAsString();
    User user = User.fromJson(json.decode(contents));
    String name = user.NameLast + ", " + user.NameFirst;
    print(name);
    l.add(name);
  }
  return l;
}
```

returns the list `l` and then processes the asyc `forEach(...)` callbacks

If you change it to

```
Future<List<String>> readHeaderData() async {
  List<String> l = new List();
  List<String> files = await readHeaders(); // Gets filenames
  for(var filename in files) {  /// <<<<==== changed line
    final file = await File(filename);
    String contents = await file.readAsString();
    User user = User.fromJson(json.decode(contents));
    String name = user.NameLast + ", " + user.NameFirst;
    print(name);
    l.add(name);
  }
  return l;
}
```

the function will not return before all filenames are processed.

```
files.forEach((filename) async {
```

means that you can use `await` inside the callback, but `forEach` doesn't care about what `(filename) async {...}` returns.

Comment: That worked. I appreciate the quick response.  May I ask where in the docs I could find that the difference between for and foreach, since it doesn't seem to be clearly defined when it comes to async calls.

I read through https://webdev.dartlang.org/articles/performance/event-loop and I thought that I clearly understood futures, however, there appears to be times that the "await" makes sense, and times it doesn't.  Though, now I will make sure to use for in this scenario.

This shows it, but not why...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437673/using-loops-with-futures-in-dart

Comment: There is a list `files` with a method `forEach(f)` that internally calls the function `f` you pass to it for every element in `files`. `forEach()` doesn't return anything. If you use instead `list.map(f)` then you will get one `Future` returned from `f` for each item in `files`. You can then use `await Future.all(files.map(f))` which will await all Futures and only then continue with the code that follows below. The loop `for(...) { ... }` is not just a method that calls functions passed to it, it is a language construct where statements and expressions are executed sequentially.

Comment: It's later here. Let me know if you want further explanations and i'll try to elaborate more tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks!  I had a Map instead of a list, so this answer helped as well:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52276412/map-foreach-function-exits-with-an-await-inside/52276702#52276702

Comment: what about Future<void> functions...creating a simple list from forEach and passing that list to firebase...

Answer (score 43):

Also possible

```
await Future.forEach(yourList, (T elem) async { ...async staff });
```

Answer (score 22):

To expand on  Günter's comment regarding using `list.map(f)`, here's an example of converting a `forEach` call so that it works correctly.

#### Broken example

Incorrectly assumes `forEach` will wait on futures:

```
Future<void> brokenExample(List<String> someInput) async {    
  List<String> results;

  someInput.forEach((input) async {
    String result = await doSomethingAsync(input);
    results.add(result);
  });

  return results;
}
```

#### Corrected example

Waits on the async functions to complete, using `Future.wait` and `.map()`:

```
Future<void> correctedExample(List<String> someInput) async {
  List<String> results;

  await Future.wait(someInput.map((input) async {
    String result = await doSomethingAsync(input);
    results.add(result);
  }));

  return results;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the similar issue. The problem is that dart will NOT wait for "forEach" contrary to public believe. There are two solutions:

```
1) Convert forEach to for loop as indicated by others. Another is use Future:
2) await Future.forEach(list, (item) async {
   // your code
    final result = await getMyResult();
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
Future.wait(someList.map((item) => something_returns_future(item)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Future.forEach() will execute futures sequentially. The iteration waits until the future is completed before continuing with the next element.

Future.wait() will execute futures in parallel. Returns a future which will complete once all the provided futures have completed.

See [Future class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.0.7/dart-async/Future-class.html)