# Flutter async/await doesn't work inside forEach

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I don't know what is missing here.. This is a function which is suppose to place orders from customers. The whole logic is quite simple :

If 1 single item in the cart , just executes once. If there are more, appends the order to the first order number. But for some reason its not waiting till the `orderRepo.addOrder` execution is complete initially.

```
  dynamic firstOrderNumber = 0;
  var existingOrder = false;

  void addOrder(List<Cart> carts) async {        --> Coming to add the list of orders
    carts.forEach((_cart) async {                --> Going to add each items in cart
      
             x += 1;
  print("\nVALUE of x inside addOrder = $x");     -> Adding X flag here to check
      Order _order = new Order();

      _order.productOrders = new List<ProductOrder>();
      _order.tax = _cart.product.store.defaultTax;
      _order.deliveryFee = payment.method == 'Pay on Pickup'
          ? 0
          : _cart.product.store.deliveryFee;
      OrderStatus _orderStatus = new OrderStatus();
      _orderStatus.id = '1'; 
      _order.orderStatus = _orderStatus;
      _order.deliveryAddress = payment.method == 'Pay on Pickup'
          ? new Address()
          : settingRepo.deliveryAddress.value;
      _order.hint = ' ';
      ProductOrder _productOrder = new ProductOrder();
      _productOrder.quantity = _cart.quantity;
      _productOrder.price = _cart.product.price;
      _productOrder.id = _cart.product.id;
      _productOrder.product = _cart.product;
      _productOrder.options = _cart.options;

      _order.productOrders.add(_productOrder);
      print("Current value of EXISTING : $existingOrder");
      if (!existingOrder) {
        print("\n\nEntering not existing order....\n");
        await orderRepo.addOrder(_order, this.payment).then((value) {      ---> Doesn't wait. PROBLEM
          if (value is Order) {
            print("The value is now $value");
            firstOrderNumber =
                value.id.toString(); //catching order number to append
            print("FIRSTORDERNUMBER : $firstOrderNumber");
            setState(() {
              loading = false;
            });
          }
        });
        print("Settting value of existing order now...");
        existingOrder = true;
        print("Existing order is now $existingOrder");
      }
      // print("Existing order is now $existingOrder");
      else {
        print("\n\nEntering existing order....\n");
        orderRepo
            .addAdditionalOrder(
                _productOrder, _cart, _order, firstOrderNumber, this.payment)
            .then((value) {
          if (value is Order) {
            setState(() {
              loading = false;
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

**OUTPUT from console :**

```
I/flutter ( 6925): VALUE of x inside addOrder = 1
I/flutter ( 6925): Current value of EXISTING : false
I/flutter ( 6925): Entering not existing order....
I/flutter ( 6925): VALUE of x inside addOrder = 2    ---> See the problem. It came back to increment X before the await is complete.  
I/flutter ( 6925): Current value of EXISTING : false
I/flutter ( 6925): Entering not existing order....
```

//Now it is giving the result of the AWAIT which it should have waited for before.....

```
I/flutter ( 6925): The response of first order is : <JSON RESPONSE from first addOrder execution...coming late..>
I/flutter ( 6925): The value is now Instance of 'Order'
I/flutter ( 6925): FIRSTORDERNUMBER : 141
I/flutter ( 6925): Settting value of existing order now...
I/flutter ( 6925): Existing order is now true
I/flutter ( 6925): The response of first order is :
```

Any hints ? How can i NOT EXECUTE ANYTHING ELSE UNTILL  `await orderRepo.addOrder(_order, this.payment).then((value) {` is complete ??? Been doing trial n error for good few days

Comment: I've also recently had that problem. The problem with `forEach` when there is an `await` keyword inside it, is that it will skip the `forEach` function and execute it later on. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51106934/my-async-call-is-returning-before-list-is-populated-in-foreach-loop

Comment: Exactly! That's what i'm seeing... skips await & executes in the end... Isn't forEach the right choice then ??

Comment: No ,`Iterable.forEach` is not the right choice.  It does not expect an asynchronous callback.  Just use a normal `for` loop.  Normal `for` loops are more readable, more flexible (`break` and `continue` work), more general (no pitfalls like this), and more efficient (no extra callback).  If, however, you still really prefer using a `forEach` style, you instead should use [`Future.forEach`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Future/forEach.html).

Comment: Thank you so much @Uni & @jamesdlin!!! I moved to for & all is well now... Thank you again !!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My async call is returning before list is populated in forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51106934/my-async-call-is-returning-before-list-is-populated-in-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 3):

Try ***map()*** like this

```
await Future.wait(carts.map((_cart)async{

  //your code here


}));
```

Comment: Tried this & got :     Function expressions can't be named.
Try removing the name, or moving the function expression to a function declaration statement.dart(named_function_expression)        as the error, am i missing something ?

Comment: @AdrianKarr I updated the code it had syntax error now try it again.

Comment: Got rid of errors.. but didn't meet the use case. It's still skipping the await to next. I just modified my code adding an 'X' flag to make things more clear with new OUTPUT from console. Can you please take a look to make some suggestions ?

Comment: I saw your code, why are you adding then while using await ? thats the value you want to wait for using await ( the same inside then(value))?

Comment: it should be sth like this 'var value = await orderRepo.addOrder(_order, this.payment);' then use the value directly without using then, if you are awaiting you should remove all the 'then' statements and the value use it directly without nesting it

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions/help. I really appreciate your inputs. But apparently it turned out that forEach doesn't care about async waits... I switched to a for loop & all is well now! Thank you again..

Comment: that was why I recommended to use map instead of forEach, anyways glad it worked !

Comment: I see... I'm kinda just bootstrapping on  flutter.. learnign from my mistakes :)

Answer (score 1):

> I think it should work for you!
>
> ```
> myFunc() async {
>   for(File file in files) {
>     await saveFiles(file);
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: That's what i did & reported not to be working. Thank you

Comment: You can try await for loop

Answer (score 1):

that solved my issue.

```
for (var item in items) {
  await function(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instate of using then function simply use await.

```
if (!existingOrder) {
    print("\n\nEntering not existing order....\n");
    var value = await orderRepo.addOrder(_order, this.payment);
    if (value is Order) {
        print("The value is now $value");
        firstOrderNumber = value.id.toString();
        print("FIRSTORDERNUMBER : $firstOrderNumber");
        setState(() {
          loading = false;
        });
      }
    print("Settting value of existing order now...");
    existingOrder = true;
    print("Existing order is now $existingOrder");
  }
```

Comment: I tried this following your Suggestion @Tipu.  But the control goes back to execute the next forEach item before the first await is complete....Any suggestions ?

Comment: I got this covered by changing forEach to a for loop..  Thank you for your inputs