# Flutter for loop containing .then statement completing first half then second half

Tags: flutter, asynchronous

I have a list called `wastedProducts` which I want to iterate through and create a new list, `wastedProductsSet` based on each item in the original list.

This is the code I have to do that:

```
for (var productHeld in wastedProducts) {
      if (wastedProductsSetNames.contains(productHeld.masterCat)) {
        print("duplicate ${productHeld.masterCat}");
      } else {
        _wastedCount = wastedProducts
            .where((p) => p.masterCat == productHeld.masterCat)
            .fold(0,(amountWasted, product) => amountWasted + product.amountWasted);

        _masterCat = Firestore.instance
            .collection('masterCategories')
            .document(productHeld.masterCat);

// repeats the above for each item before completing the below for each item

        _masterCat.get().then(
          (value) {
            baseUnit = value.data['baseUnit'];
            if (baseUnit == null) {
              baseUnit = '';
            } else {
              baseUnit = value.data['baseUnit'];
            }

            wastedProductsSet.add(
              WastedProduct(
                productName: productHeld.masterCat,
                wastedCount: _wastedCount.toInt(),
                baseUnit: baseUnit,
              ),
            );

            wastedProductsSetNames.add(productHeld.masterCat);
          },
        );
      }
    }
```

Based on the print statements, I can see it is completing the code up to the `_masterCat.get().then(` line and doing that for each item in `wastedProducts`, then completing the code below `_masterCat.get().then(` for each item.

I assume it must have something to do with the asynchronous nature of the `.then` but cannot work out what the problem is.

I originally was using `.forEach` instead of `for (var productHeld in wastedProducts)` but changed based on the answer in this post [My async call is returning before list is populated in forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51106934/my-async-call-is-returning-before-list-is-populated-in-foreach-loop).

Comment: Yes, `.then()` does not wait for the result. Maybe you want to `await` the call?

Comment: Like the above comment suggests, Futures are asynchronous and the for loop will not wait for your `then` block to finish executing. You should use async await instead but note that if you use an async block in the build function the build function will not wait for it so you might also have to use FutureBuilder

Comment: I have tried using async await in various places but still cannot work out how to do it. I have now tried simplifying by making the ```baseUnit``` an attribute of the ```productHeld``` but it is still returning as ```null``` even though I can see the ```productHeld``` items in the list have a ```baseUnit``` set.