# Flutter Dio add MultipartFile object to Map dynamicaly

Tags: flutter, dart, multipartform-data, dio

I have custom data:

```
File avatar = File('path/to/file');

Map<String, dynamic> data = {
  'name': 'John',
  'avatar': avatar
}
```

How I can send this my data as FormData object to server?

I tried create object of `MultipartFile` class by looping my data but in my case sending file path as string instance of file. Here is my code:

```
data.forEach((key, value) {
  if (value is File) {
    String fileName = value.path.split('/').last;
    data.update(key, (value) async {
      return await MultipartFile.fromFile(value.path, filename: fileName);
    });
  }
});

FormData formData = FormData.fromMap(data);
var response = await dio.post("/send", data: formData);
```

But using `Dio` I can upload file something like this:

```
FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
    "name": "wendux",
    "age": 25,
    "file": await MultipartFile.fromFile(file.path,filename: fileName)
});
```

Why I can't dynamically add `MultipartFile` to my `Map` ?

Answer (score 1):

You are not awaiting for your data

```
await Future.wait(data.map((k, v){
if(v is File){
v = await MultipartFile.fromFile(value.path, filename: fileName);
}
  return MapEntry(k, v);
}));
```

Please look into [My async call is returning before list is populated in forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51106934/my-async-call-is-returning-before-list-is-populated-in-foreach-loop)

Comment: `{status: false, error: {message: No file chosen., type: ERROR_FILE_NOT_PROVIDED, code: 10}}`

Comment: Doesn't send file

Answer (score 1):

You can send it without dio. Here I write the whole code including the libraries and response.Please test the below code becuase in my case dio is not working and your case is very similar to my case.

Just `send it with simple http request`

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http_parser/http_parser.dart';
import 'package:mime/mime.dart';

   Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',        
    };

    Map jsonMap = {
      "name": "wendux",
      "age": 25,          
    };
 String imagePath, // add the image path in varible 

 var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(url));
    request.headers.addAll(headers);
    request.files.add(
      http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
        'orderStatusUpdate',
        utf8.encode(json.encode(jsonMap)),
        contentType: MediaType(
          'application',
          'json',
          {'charset': 'utf-8'},
        ),
      ),
    );

    if (imagePath != null) {
      final mimeTypeData = lookupMimeType(imagePath).split('/');
      final file = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('images', imagePath,
          contentType: MediaType(mimeTypeData[0], mimeTypeData[1]));
      print((mimeTypeData[0].toString())); // tells picture or not
      print((mimeTypeData[1].toString())); // return extention
      request.files.add(file);
    }

    http.StreamedResponse streamedResponse = await request.send();
    var response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.body);
```