# How to set parameterised content type in put request in multipart request

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I am facing issues to pass requestDTO object in form-data using application/json content type.

I used below code using Dio library. But in Dio parameters values passed as a string. I got missing requestDTO object error from the server.

```
Map<String, String> header = Map<String, String>();
header['Authorization'] = 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI4NzY1NDMyMTA5IiwiYXV0aCI6IlJPTEVfQ09OVFJBQ1RPUiIsImV4cCI6MTYxNTYzNjIxMX0._pBVg6aWSl2K2bf416w1YnxYpQeEckL1Go9b_TRgaVruwcyh7tB5OdY9ujSiORn3rVpE39kPIX5zTTuwSJC3lQ';
header['content-type'] = 'multipart/form-data';


Map<String, dynamic> params = Map<String, dynamic>();
params['requestDTO'] = '{\n  "email": "c1@yopmail.com",\n  "firstName": "Contractor",\n  "fullName": "Contractor",\n  "imageUrl": "string",\n  "lastName": "two",\n  "phoneNumber": "8765432109",\n  "prAddressDTO": {\n    "addressLine": "string",\n    "city": "string",\n    "country": "string",\n    "id": 7009,\n    "latitude": 0,\n    "longitude": 0,\n    "prUserId": 6104,\n    "state": "string",\n    "zipcode": "string"\n  },\n  "prBusinessInfoDTO": {\n    "businessLicense": "string",\n    "businessName": "string",\n    "experience": 0,\n    "id": 6251,\n    "liabilityInsurance": "string",\n    "noOfWorkers": 0,\n    "notes": "string",\n    "prUserId": 6104,\n    "projectsCompleted": 0,\n    "servicesCategory": "string",\n    "servicesSubCategory": "string",\n    "stateRegistration": "string",\n    "taxIdentificationNumber": "string"\n  },\n  "userType": "CONTRACTOR"\n}';


// Create form data Request
FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap(params);

final option = Options(headers: header);
try {
  final response = await this.dio.put('http://180.211.99.164:9091/api/contractor/me', data: formData, options: option, onSendProgress: (sent, total) => Logger().v("uploadFile ${sent / total}"));
  this._handleNetworkSuccess(response: response);
} on DioError catch (error) {
  this._handleDioNetworkError(error: error);
}
```

[image: Request screen shot]

Answer (score -1):

Kindly check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65737169/13439617

It sends the request without `DIO`