# Error adding List of Map to Firebase: Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, async-await

I am trying to add a `List` of `Map` to my Firestore but it doesn't seem to work.

The reason it is not working is because the write function to Firestore is being called before I can assign a value to the `Map` and add it to my `List`. The issue seems to be with `async` `await` I suppose but I can't see anything wrong with the code.

This is the function that I am using to add Order Requests

```
Future<String> addOrder(
    DateTime startTime,
    DateTime endTime,
    CartItem cartProduct,
    double total,
    String restName,
    String restLocation,
  ) async {
    var userId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
    final timestamp = DateTime.now();
    String error = '';
    String restError = '';
    String id;
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> restItemsMap = [];

    try {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users/$userId/orders')
          .add(
            {
              'amount': total,
              'dateTime': timestamp.toIso8601String(),
              'restaurantName': cartProduct.restaurantName,
              'restaurantLocation': restLocation,
              'startTime': startTime,
              'restaurantId': cartProduct.id,
              'status': OrderStatus.Pending.toString(),
              'endTime': endTime,
            },
          )
          .then((value) => id = value.id)
          .catchError((error) {
            print('Error adding new order initialization: $error');
            return error.toString();
          });

      cartProduct.restaurantItems.forEach(
        (restItem) async {
          // print('ordered item: ${cp}');
          await FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('users')
              .doc(userId)
              .collection('orders')
              .doc(id)
              .collection('items')
              .doc(restItem.id)
              .set(
            {
              'name': restItem.name,
              'quantity': restItem.quantity,
              'price': restItem.price,
            },
          ).catchError((error) {
            print('Adding rest items initialization: $error');
            return error.toString();
          });
        },
      );

      /// RESTAURANT REQUEST

      cartProduct.restaurantItems.forEach(
        (element) async {
          Map<String, dynamic> restItemMap = {};
          final restData = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('restaurants')
              .doc(cartProduct.id)
              .collection('restaurantItems')
              .doc(element.id)
              .get()
              .catchError((error) {
            print('adding rest item error: $error');
            return error.toString();
          });
          if (restData.data()['quantity'] - element.quantity >= 0) {
            
            restItemMap = {
              'id': element.id,
              'name': element.name,
              'quantity': element.quantity,
              'price': element.price,
            };
            restItemsMap.add(restItemMap);
            print('REST MAP: $restItemMap');
          } else {
            return 'OUT_OF_STOCK';
          }
        },
      );
      print('REST ARRAY MAP: $restItemsMap');

      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('restaurants')
          .doc(cartProduct.id)
          .collection('orderRequests')
          .doc(id)
          .set({
        'startTime': startTime,
        'endTime': endTime,
        'amount': total,
        'dateTime': timestamp.toIso8601String(),
        'orderId': id,
        'status': OrderStatus.Pending.toString(),
        'items': restItemsMap,
      }).catchError((error) {
        print('adding rest item error: $error');
        return error.toString();
      });

      notifyListeners();
      return 'SUCCESS';
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
      return 'ERROR';
    }
  }
```

The `print('REST ARRAY MAP: $restItemsMap');` statement is being called before `print('REST MAP: $restItemMap');`

This is the **OUTPUT** I am getting:

> flutter: REST ARRAY MAP: []

> flutter: REST MAP: {id:bcUM4KmfqCdZ2ffafPDT, name: Donut Meal, quantity: 1, price: 50.0}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async call don't wokr in a `forEach` loop. They will be executed but your code will just went trough the loop without awaiting them. That is the reason you see that behaviour.

The best solution is to store the data into an Array and use a `for in` loop and the `async` will work as expected.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51107013/5519300) is a similar problem like yours with a solution example.