# How to extract data recursively from firestore?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have some documents in Firestore that contain references to other documents in other collections, I'm trying to extract one object (called order) that should look like:

```
{
  "field1": "value1",
  "field2": "value2",
  ...
  "offer": {
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": "value2",
    ...
    "address": "string value"
  }
}
```

I wrote this function:

```
 Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getDetailsByDocumentReference(
      DocumentReference ref) async {
    final document = await ref.get();
    final data = document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    final Map<String, dynamic> result = {};

    data.forEach((field, value) async {
      if (value is DocumentReference) {
        result[field] = await getDetailsByDocumentReference(value);
      } else {
        result[field] = value;
      }
    });
    return result;
}
```

The function is called this way:

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getOrderDetailsById(String id) async {
    DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> docRef = _db.doc('orders/$id');
    Map<String, dynamic> result = await getDetailsByDocumentReference(docRef);
    return result;
  }
```

The final result is only a map with one values that are not references

```
{
      "field1": "value1",
      "field2": "value2"
}
```

All async calls are made with await, what am I missing?

Comment: Finally found the answer here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51106934/my-async-call-is-returning-before-list-is-populated-in-foreach-loop

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you referencing the `collection` anywhere. It seems this:

`DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> docRef = _db.doc('orders/$id');`

Should instead be this:

`DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> docRef = _db.collection('orders').doc(id);`

[Get a document in Firestore with Fluter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#dart)

Comment: No it works, I get the document, it's when it start digging that the result is returned and the other asynchronous code goes but the result was already returned