# Flutter firestore return Future<List<Data>> returns empty

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a function that retrieve a List of data as a Future.

```
final CollectionReference _departmentHoursCollection =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('departmentsHours');

Future<List<DepartmentHour>> isUnfinishedGK(List<String> sites) async {
    sites.asMap().forEach((key, value) async {
      QuerySnapshot departmentsHoursSnapshot = await _departmentHoursCollection
          .where('siteName', isEqualTo: value)
          .where('justification', isEqualTo: 'working')
          .get();
      if (departmentsHoursSnapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        departmentsHoursSnapshot.docs.asMap().forEach((key, value) async {
          var document = await value.reference.get();
          print(document.data());
          _temporal.add(DepartmentHour.fromMap(document.data()));
        });
      }
    });
    print("size: ${_temporal.length}");
    return _temporal;
  }
```

however when i print size at the end, it keeps showing:

> I/flutter (20592): size: 0

But the data is being fetched and added to the variable: **_temporal**:

> I/flutter (20592): {globalTime: 24304, endHour: 06:00, startedTime:
> Timestamp(seconds=1602329908, nanoseconds=453000000),
> departmentHourDetails: [{globalTime: 24300, endJobTime:
> Timestamp(seconds=1602354212, nanoseconds=456000000), department:
> Grind Room, startJobTime: Timestamp(seconds=1602329911,
> nanoseconds=766000000)}, {globalTime: 24299, endJobTime:
> Timestamp(seconds=1602354212, nanoseconds=456000000), department: Main
> Production, startJobTime: Timestamp(seconds=1602329913,
> nanoseconds=94000000)}], startHour: 22:00, scheduleDate:
> Timestamp(seconds=1602306000, nanoseconds=0), finishedTime:
> Timestamp(seconds=1602329908, nanoseconds=453000000), siteName: SMD,
> justification: working}

anyone knows how to return the List with the fetched data instead of returning a [].

Comment: is this `print(document.data());` appearing before `print("size: ${_temporal.length}");` in the output

Comment: yes, that information is displayed before the print("size:${temporal.length}");

Comment: try to use **Future.forEach**, i think that the list is being returned before the loop is completed.

Comment: That was the issue :) i didn't know about the existence of a Future.forEach, please post your comment as an answer so i can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem you can use **Future.forEach()**, that waits for each Future to be completed before moving to the next element, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437673/using-loops-with-futures-in-dart).

Example:

```
Future<List<String>> myFuture(List<String> names) async {
  List<String> newNames = [];

  await Future.forEach(names, (name) async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      newNames.add(name);
    });
  });

  return newNames;
}
```